# Permission denied trying to mkdir in build with jenkins and kubernetes

Tags: docker, jenkins, permissions

I need to create a folder in one of the stages of a build in jenkins, but I'm getting a permission error when it tries to run mkdir.
dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:latest

USER root

WORKDIR /root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg2

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common curl git jq wget unzip

RUN curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.15.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz| tar -v -C /usr/local -xz

RUN export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

#
# Docker
#
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
RUN export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

WORKDIR /app/src/
```

Stage of Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('Restore') {

                try {
                    timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') {

                        dir('.') {
                            sh "mv * /root/go/src/Proj/"
                        }

                        dir('/root/go/src/Proj/') {
                             sh "mkdir ./${repoName}"
                        }
                        
                    }
                } catch (Exception err) {
                    cleanWS()
                    error("[FAILED]: " + err.getMessage())
                }
            }
```

The mv command works fine, but when it comes to mkdir, it gives me this error:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /root/go/src
```

Does anyone know how could I set this permission?

Comment: Use fileOperations plugin to avoid this kind of issue, else allow permission using windows batch command for those location

Comment: I gave only the folder example, but I need to do other operations that require permission too, such as a "go get" command. and this command also gives me the same permission error.